# Running several .dll files as child processes from WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, process, add-in

Is there a way to call several .dll files from a winform as child processes and it can automatically restart the process if the .dll is failed to be called? I am thinking to use multiple "AddInProcess" to call these .dll files.

I would appreciate if anyone could give a simple code to do this.

Comment: Since you are looking for simple code you should be able to easily write one comining `Process.Start`, `Assembly.Load`, `Activator.CreateInstance` and `MethodInfo.Invoke`... When you have it - update your post with concrete problem you hit.

Comment: You can have a look at [MEF](https://mef.codeplex.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by reflection:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\path\\MyDll.dll");

Type type = assembly.GetType("MyClass");

object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

You could, for example, create an Interface and make your child DLLs implement it.
Then when you call the reflection, you check if any object implements it and instantiate that object.